# FormData not working properly with 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, multipartform-data, form-data

I'm trying to send a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` form through `fetch`.

My issue is that the format of the sent data is invalid like follows:

```
  "FormData {
  [Symbol(state)]: [
    {
      name: '------WebKitFormBoundaryhPzR6LljgR6oqP3V\r\n' +
        'Content-Disposition: form-data; name',
      value: '"_id"\r\n' +
        '\r\n' +
        '2\r\n' +
        '------WebKitFormBoundaryhPzR6LljgR6oqP3V\r\n' +
        'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="zied"\r\n' +
        '\r\n' +
        'here I am\r\n' +
        '------WebKitFormBoundaryhPzR6LljgR6oqP3V--\r\n'
    }
  ]
}"
```

Here's the code that sends it:

```
function startWithTemplate(event) {
    const id = event.detail?._id;
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('_id', id)
    formData.append('zied', "here I am")
    fetch('?/template', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        body: formData
    })
        .then(response => {
            console.log('Response:', response);
        })
        .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error:', error);
            });
}
```

So I created a `<form>` and tried to send data through it, and the format is completely different:

```
<form action='?/template' method='post'>
    <input type='hidden' name='_id' value='2'>
    <input type='hidden' name='zied' value='kidding'>
    <button type='submit' >Send</button>
</form>
```

sends:

```
FormData {
  [Symbol(state)]: [ { name: '_id', value: '2' }, { name: 'zied', value: 'kidding' } ]
}
```

Checking the payload source, I found it was : `"_id=2&zied=kidding"`, so I'm able to work around this by typing my values without using the `FromData` object, but I'd like to be able to handle more complex cases too

Comment: Simple, use `URLSearchParams` instead of `FormData`... `fetch('?/template', { method: 'POST', body: new URLSearchParams({ _id: id, zied: 'here I am' }) })`